# Why isn't content written to a new text file?

Tags: c++, file-io

The program opens the file, creates a new.txt file, and opens it, but it doesn't fill the new.txt, and then proceeds to the renaming process.

Why doesn't it write to the new file? How should I properly redo this to make it write to the new file?

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;


void out(string x)
{
    x+="\n";
    cout<<x;
}
void outn()
{
    out("");
}
void delay(int x)
{
    Sleep(x);
}
void delayS(int x)
{
    Sleep(x*1000);
}
void cs()
{
    std::system("cls");
}
void UserName(string *x)
{
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &size);
    string transition(username);
    *x=transition;
}
//use this syntax in main : string username;UserName(&username);



int main()
{


    string username;
    UserName(&username);
    /*out(username);*/


    const string namefile="preferences.txt";


    string path;

    const string beginning="C:\\Users\\";
    const string ending="\\AppData\\Roaming\\Processing\\";

    path+=beginning;
    path+=username;
    path+=ending;

    string path2;
    path2=path;
    path2+="new.txt";
    string filename2="new.txt";

    path+=namefile;



    string line76="proxy.http.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line77="3128";
    string line78="proxy.https.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line79="3128";
    string line80="proxy.socks.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line81="3128";


    fstream file;
    //fstream newfile;
    ofstream newfile(path2.c_str());

    try
    {
        file.open(path.c_str(),ios::in);
        if(!file.is_open())
        {
            throw 404;
        }
        //procédure de modif
        else
        {
            file.close();

            file.open(path.c_str());
            try
            {
                newfile.open(path2.c_str(),ios::out|ios::trunc);
                if(!newfile.is_open())
                {
                    throw 404;
                }
            }
            catch(int x)
            {
                cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : failed to open file \\new.txt\\";
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 76; i++)
            {
                std::string text;
                getline(file, text);
                newfile << text <<endl;
            }
            newfile << line76 <<endl;
            newfile << line77 <<endl;
            newfile << line78 <<endl;
            newfile << line79 <<endl;
            newfile << line80 <<endl;
            newfile << line81 <<endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 82; i < 97; i++)
            {
                std::string text;
                std::getline(file, text);
                newfile << text <<endl;
            }
            newfile << "";

        }

        file.close();
        newfile.close();
        string old1 = beginning+username+ending+"old_pref.txt";

        try
        {
            int rf=rename(path.c_str(),old1.c_str());
            if(rf!=0)
            {
                throw 911;
            }
        }
        catch(int x)
        {
            cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : Failed to rename to \\old_pref.txt\\";
        }
        try
        {
            int rf2=rename(path2.c_str(),path.c_str());
            if(rf2!=0)
            {
                throw 911;
            }
        }
        catch(int x)
        {
            cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : Failed to rename to \\preferences.txt\\";
        }


        cs();
        out("done !");
    }
    catch(int x)
    {
        cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : failed to open file \\preferences.txt\\";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ofstream newfile(path2.c_str());
```

The new file gets created here. And then, later:

```
newfile.open(path2.c_str(),ios::out|ios::trunc);
```

Here, an attempt is made to create the same file, a second time. The file is already created, and is open. An attempt to open the same `std::ofstream` object that's already open is an error, and the `std::ofstream` object is now in an error state.

With the object in the error state, all subsequent attempts to write to the stream object will fail.

Solution: create the file once, not twice.

Comment: He has an error on that 'failed to open file \\new.txt\\'. It doesn't stop the program execution however

Comment: That's because `is_open()` still succeeds. The file is open. But the stream object is in an error state.

Comment: I don't understand, don't I create it with the ofstream and open it with open ? It's already opened when created ?

Comment: I understood doing some debugging, i replaced :
`ofstream newfile(path2.c_str());`
With:
`ofstream newfile;`

And added correction to some bug I left. Now it works thx !

EDIT: moderators can close this now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code for those who'd be interested :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


void out(string x)
{
    x+="\n";
    cout<<x;
}
void outn()
{
    out("");
}
void delay(int x)
{
    Sleep(x);
}
void delayS(int x)
{
    Sleep(x*1000);
}
void cs()
{
    std::system("cls");
}
void UserName(string *x)
{
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &size);
    string transition(username);
    *x=transition;
}
//use this syntax in main : string username;UserName(&username);



int main()
{


    string username;
    UserName(&username);
    /*out(username);*/


    const string namefile="preferences.txt";


    string path;

    const string beginning="C:\\Users\\";
    const string ending="\\AppData\\Roaming\\Processing\\";

    path+=beginning;
    path+=username;
    path+=ending;

    string path2;
    path2=path;
    path2+="new.txt";
    string filename2="new.txt";

    path+=namefile;



    string line76="proxy.http.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line77="proxy.http.port=3128";
    string line78="proxy.https.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line79="proxy.https.port=3128";
    string line80="proxy.socks.host=proxy-eple.in.ac-nantes.fr";
    string line81="proxy.socks.port=3128";


    fstream file;
//fstream newfile;
    ofstream newfile/*(path2.c_str())*/;

    try
    {
        file.open(path.c_str(),ios::in);
        if(!file.is_open())
        {
            throw 404;
        }
        //procédure de modif
        else
        {
            file.close();

            file.open(path.c_str());
            try
            {
                newfile.open(path2.c_str(),ios::out|ios::trunc);
                if(!newfile.is_open())
                {
                    throw 404;
                }
            }
            catch(int x)
            {
                cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : failed to open file \\new.txt\\";
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 76; i++)
            {
                std::string text;
                getline(file, text);
                newfile << text <<endl;
            }
            newfile << line76 <<endl;
            newfile << line77 <<endl;
            newfile << line78 <<endl;
            newfile << line79 <<endl;
            newfile << line80 <<endl;
            newfile << line81 <<endl;

            //because we still need it to roll through the file before copying
            for(unsigned int i=76; i<82; i++)
            {
                std::string text;
                std::getline(file,text);
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 82; i < 97; i++)
            {
                std::string text;
                std::getline(file, text);
                newfile << text <<endl;
            }
            newfile << "";

        }

        file.close();
        newfile.close();
        string old1 = beginning+username+ending+"old_pref.txt";

        try
        {
            int rf=rename(path.c_str(),old1.c_str());
            if(rf!=0)
            {
                throw 911;
            }
        }
        catch(int x)
        {
            cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : Failed to rename to \\old_pref.txt\\";
        }
        try
        {
            int rf2=rename(path2.c_str(),path.c_str());
            if(rf2!=0)
            {
                throw 911;
            }
        }
        catch(int x)
        {
            cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : Failed to rename to \\preferences.txt\\";
        }


        cs();
        out("done !");
    }
    catch(int x)
    {
        cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : failed to open file \\preferences.txt\\";
    }


    return 0;
}
```